# google cloud endpoint method with multiple response message

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a google could enpoint method that I need to be able to return either a `MaleResponseMessage` or a `FemaleResponseMessage`. Is there a way to specify that such as with

```
@endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, [MaleResponseMessage, FemaleResponseMessage])
```

There is of course the option of declaring a super message class, say, `PersonResponseMessage` to wrap either `MaleResponseMessage` or `FemaleResponseMessage`. But is there something similar to the snippet above?

EDIT:

Trying to implement my own proposal, I got stuck. The only thing the two message types have in common is the request: the exact same request fields (with an additional boolean `female=true/false`) for `PersonRequest`. The `MaleResponseMessage` and the `FemaleResponseMessage` have no field in common. So I am using one endpoint method, as @bossylobster shows, where I check

```
if request.female : # request.female == True
    return get_female(etc, etc)
else: # request.female == False // implies male
    return get_male(etc,etc)
```

For the response, I need something like

```
class PersonResponse(messages.Message):
  if ??? :
     item = messages.MessageField(MaleResponseMessage,1)
  else:
      item = messages.MessageField(FemaleResponseMessage,1)
```

I am not sure what to check `???` for. First, I thought about `isinstance` or `type`. But how would I do that? Would the below work?

```
class PersonResponse(messages.Message):
  if type(Message()) == MaleResponseMessage :
     item = messages.MessageField(MaleResponseMessage,1)
  else:
      item = messages.MessageField(FemaleResponseMessage,1)
```

Comment: What I like about your question is that you seem to actually know your stuff. You are just stuck on this issue. :) Remember to share your final solution if @bossylobster or someone else is not able to help but you get there anyway.

Comment: @Katedral Pillon, you're misunderstaning what `messages.Message` subclasses are doing. They are there for you to create a protocol buffer container definition, so you can only list static fields, no conditional `if` statements are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no. You can have only one response and one request schema; this is because they are registered with Google's API infrastructure and having a strict schema is what provides the speed and efficiency of requests.

Your best bet would be to combine the fields needed for each male and female into a single model class and do your own validation.

A possible solution could look like

```
from protorpc import messages

class Gender(messages.Enum):
    MALE = 0
    FEMALE = 1

class GenderRequest(messages.Enum):
    gender = messages.EnumField(Gender, 1, required=True)

class PersonResponse(messages.Message):
    gender = messages.EnumField(Gender, 1)
    # shared fields
    # female specific fields
    # male specific fields
```

and then in your actual method

```
    @endpoints.method(GenderRequest, PersonMessage, ...)
    def my_method(self, request):
      if request.gender == Gender.MALE:
          return male_response(request)
      elif request.gender == Gender.FEMALE:
          return female_response(request)
      else:
          # This should never occur since gender is required
          raise endpoints.BadRequestException('Gender not set.')
```

where `male_response` and `female_response` are methods which create instances of `PersonMessage` corresponding to male and female.

Comment: Many thanks for the code snippet. My particular problem is that `MaleResponseMessage` and `FemaleResponseMessage` have no fields in common. Please see my edit for more details. Many thanks.

Comment: You can try following 2 approaches:  1, Use the option given by @bossylobster and create a common response message like PersonResponse which has all fields required for female and all fields required for male. Now while sending the actual response, based on gender, assign values only to required fields for this gender and put blank or 0 in other fields for the other gender.    2, Or else if your MaleResponse and FemaleResponse have fields of same type (like Messagefield) and in equal numbers(say 5), then use a general message which generic fields and assign values based on the chosen gender.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different endpoint methods.